# (ngSubmit) doesn't trigger when i click on button with type=submit

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i have an issue, which should be basic, but that i can't resolve....

When i click on my `save` button, which is of type submit, my event `ngSubmit` doesn't trigger.

i paste you my code

my-form.componant.ts:

```
export class ProfileFormComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any = {libelle: 'test', id=1};
  libelle: String;
  profilForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private service: ReflexTableService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profilForm = new FormGroup({
    libelle: new FormControl(this.data.libelle ),
    id: new FormControl({ value: this.data.id, disabled: true })
  });
 }

 onSubmit() {
   console.log(this.data);
   console.log(this.profilForm.value);
  }
}
```

my-form.componant.html:

```
<div [formGroup]="profilForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="profilForm.pristine" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">Libelle:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="libelle">
    </label>
    <label class="center-block">Id:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="id">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: Your `ngSubmit` directive is on a `<div>` not a `<form>` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit#usage

Comment: it work, thank you dude...

Comment: @PatrickEvans If you make that the answer, you will get credit for it.